# Trying to find variable names from $user array

Tags: users

I need to manually pull through user images and and users first name for a comment section, but i cant find what these array items are named, if anybody knows please tell me and or tell me how to find similar information in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is use the devel module.

Once enabled you can use the `dpm($variable)` function to have it printed out on the screen.

Another (more complex to set up) solution would be to use xdebug and a debugger.

Comment: downloaded and installed devel but Execute php code in development didnt display anything, which development link/tool should i use?

Comment: i found what i was looking for in variable editor, but if you could let me know where to find the console for future reference i would appreciate it, thanks for turning me onto devel module though, its very helpful.

Comment: If you go to /devel/php it will give you an area where you can test some php.

Comment: With devel module you can active kint also and then debug like this `kint($var)`. If you use kint on delvel/php, `kint($var); die();`